# Embedding a Script in NextJS with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am attempting to embed a script from GameChanger (https://web.gc.com) and this is the code they provided me:

```
<!-- Put this div wherever you want the widget to be embedded -->
<div id="gc-scoreboard-widget-umpl"></div>

<!-- Put this before the closing </body> tag -->
<script src="https://widgets.gc.com/static/js/sdk.v1.js"></script>
<script>
    window.GC.scoreboard.init({
        target: "#gc-scoreboard-widget-umpl",
        widgetId: "UUID HERE",
        maxVerticalGamesVisible: 4,
    })
</script>
```

I'm using NextJS 14 with Typescript.  My Component looks like this:

```
import Script from "next/script";

export default function GameChangerScoreboard() {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src="https://widgets.gc.com/static/js/sdk.v1.js" />
      <Script
        id="gc-scoreboard-init"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
                    window.GC.scoreboard.init({
                        target: 'gc-scoreboard-widget-umpl',
                        widgetId: "UUID HERE",
                        maxVerticalGamesVisible: 4
                    });
                `,
        }}
      />
      <div id="gc-scoreboard-widget-umpl"></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to do this:

```
VM938:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scoreboard')
    at <anonymous>:2:31
    at loadScript (script.js:140:19)
    at eval (script.js:223:17)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:18071:39)
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19742:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19826:29)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19824:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19824:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19824:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19824:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19824:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19824:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19824:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19824:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19918:25)
    at recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:19808:21)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:19824:25)
(anonymous) @ VM938:2
loadScript @ script.js:140
eval @ script.js:223
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:18071
commitHookPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19742
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19826
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19824
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19918
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19808
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:19832
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19799
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:22446
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:22398
eval @ react-dom.development.js:22188
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:200
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:178
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:416
Show 100 more frames
Show less
```

I'm not sure what my error is.  I'm assuming it has something to do with not having the type information for the embed, but I'm not sure.  Thank you in advance for any help.

I initially tried just copying and pasting the code in, which wouldn't compile.  CoPilot recommended that I use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML which led to my change in the code.  I'm not sure what next to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error suggests that when the second Script is run, the window.GC object is not yet defined. I'm assuming it is created by the first script, so ideally you want the second script to run only after the first one is loaded and ran.
You can do this with the onLoad function in the NextJs Script component, so you use only the first script and execute the second part after its loaded, like this:

```
 <Script
    src="https://widgets.gc.com/static/js/sdk.v1.js"
    onLoad={() => {
      window.GC.scoreboard.init({
        target: "#gc-scoreboard-widget-umpl",
        widgetId: "UUID HERE",
        maxVerticalGamesVisible: 4,
      });
    }}
  />
```

Another thing you could try is to add a useEffect hook on your component that does the init stuff only after guaranteeing the window.GC object exists, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (window.GC && window.GC.scoreboard) {
      window.GC.scoreboard.init({
        target: "#gc-scoreboard-widget-umpl",
        widgetId: "UUID HERE",
        maxVerticalGamesVisible: 4,
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: I did the first one on my own just now, but is there a benefit to one over the other?

Comment: Nice answer-- I was about to post something similar!  The effect you posted will only run on mount, though, and may never happen to find the `GC.scoreboard` object.  You might want to add a `setInterval` here to poll for that field, or some other approach that takes that in to account.  You might even set some component state in `onLoad` that would trigger a re-render, and your effect could depend on that...

Comment: The way the component will look like if you implement just the useEffect, the scoreboard will try to init when the component renders and if the GC doest exist, it will simply not do anything, so its more like a safe guard if the component for some reason rerenders but the first script is still loaded, because in that case the scoreboard would not init again. I'm not sure if this can even happen with the Script component though, if someone knows please let me know too!